# Dynamic Button Width using WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpf-4.0

I am trying to create a control that performs several animations on mouse over event of a button. The first functionality is that, the button should take padding=2 and occupy the entire columns. I am not able to do that; if I am trying to decrease the width of the button on mouseover, I am able to do, but when I am trying to increase the width, the button is expanding but the expanded part is not visible. How to implement the same ?

I am using the below code in control template. Please suggest changes :-

```
<!--Create a control template for button-->
<ControlTemplate x:Key="buttonAnimate" TargetType="Button">
    <Grid Name="myGrid">
        <Button Name="myButton" Background="{TemplateBinding Background }" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}">
        </Button>
    <Border Name="MyBorder" BorderBrush="Orange" BorderThickness="3" CornerRadius="2"></Border>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkRed" TargetName="MyBorder"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="200" TargetName="myButton"/>
            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" TargetName="myGrid"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="300" TargetName="myButton"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="300" TargetName="MyBorder"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2" TargetName="myButton"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should be using Storyboards to achieve this. Refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312.aspx

Answer (score 0):

your Button is being clipped by the Grid.
Try to set ClipsToBounds property to false or try this:

```
public class MyButton : Button
{
    protected override Geometry GetLayoutClip(Size layoutSlotSize)
    {
        return ClipToBounds ? base.GetLayoutClip(layoutSlotSize) : null;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.